# WordPress running on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress

"An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums."
Trying to run WordPress on localhost.
WP displays above error message when trying to install new plugins, adding a new theme.
Tried

```
 1)Disabled all plugins and then reactivating them

 2)reinstalled WP

 3)define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true); in wp-config.php

 4)site URL is not left blank

 5)Validated that the filesystem allows WordPress to write to the WordPress directories.
```

[debug.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsEuL.png)

Comment: Did you enable WP_DEBUG? If not please do and see if there is any error message.

Comment: Yeah, tried that. No error messages in debug.log. Sometimes stack trace prints:-  link mentioned in question.

Comment: Add and configure xdebug in the php.ini, set up xdebug debugging in your IDE. Search for that text in the code, add there a breakpoint, and after the execution stopped there go up the stack until you find something.

Answer (score 0):

What is the PHP version you are using to install Wordpress on localhost?
WordPress requires PHP 5.2.4+ and MySQL 5.0+

Comment: Using PHP-5.3.4  MySQL-5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into your wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Comment: Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/an-unexpected-error-occurred-49/) link for a solution on wordpress support forum. There are few alternatives to resolve this issue. It depends on the cause of an issue.